# Audio file playing in Android Studio Emulator, but not on my actual Phone (LG ARISTO 2 PLUS)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio

Audio file playing in `Android Studio Emulator`, but not on my actual Phone.

Using media player in android studio to play `.mp3` file. everything works fine in emulator... but after exporting to `.apk` to my phone,the `.mp3` file is not playing at all. any help is much appreciated

here is my mainactivity file:

```
import javax.swing.text.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  TextView plainText; // sets variable for plaintext which user enters
  TextView textView;
  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

  public void select(View view) {

    plainText = findViewById(R.id.editText);// why is this necessary for activity to run
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alarm);
    try {
      int time = Integer.parseInt(plainText.getText().toString());

      int milliSecond = time * 1000;
      // value is needed in milliseconds so we convert value into milliseconds
      new CountDownTimer(milliSecond, 1000) {// 1000ms is 1 second

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUnitFinished) {
          textView.setText("0.0" + String.valueOf(millisUnitFinished / 1000));

        }

        public void onFinish() {
          textView.setText("Times Up!");
          mediaPlayer.start();

        }

      }.start();

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Value in integer Only", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

  }

  public void stop(View view) {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
  }

  @Override // overide command basically overides the mainactivity externsion from mainactivity
            // class so that it can run its own methods without
  // essentially being bound by main activity classes extension
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to add `new`.

Change `mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alarm);`

To:  `mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer().create(this, R.raw.alarm);`